# Swift https POST request for the PlantNet API

Tags: swift, https

Currently I'm trying to program an https post request for the Plant Net API (https://my.plantnet.org/account/doc#) in Swift. I want to have one to five images inside my https post request and each image has as parameter organ (in my case this is always "leaf"). When I try to run my application, I get the error code 400 "Invalid multipart payload format". I'm not sure how I can solve this problem.

```
//
//  PlantRecognition.swift
//  Happy Plant
//
//  Insert several images of the same plant (maximum of 5) and get the result list
//

import Foundation
import UIKit

class PlantRecognition {
    
    //List with images of the plant to be recognized
    var imageList: [UIImage] = []
    
    //Api key for the plant net access
    var API_KEY: String = "MY_API_KEY"
    var plantNetURL: String = ""
    
    
    init() {
        //Set plant net url after class initialization
        plantNetURL = "https://my-api.plantnet.org/v2/identify/all?api-key{\(API_KEY)}"
    }
    
    func recognizeImages(images: [UIImage]) {
        //Try to create the api endpoint url
        guard let apiEndpoint = URL(string: "https://my-api.plantnet.org/v2/identify/all?api-key=\(API_KEY)") else {print("Error creating api endpoint"); return }
        
        //Convert the UIImages to jpeg
        let imagesJPG = convertImagesToJPEG(images: images)
        
        //Create url request
        var request = URLRequest(url: apiEndpoint)
        
        //Set the http method to post (local images)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        //Create boundary which marks the start/end of the request body
        let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
        
        //Set value for our specific http header field
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        //Set the mime type to jpg (we will convert our UIImages to jpg)
        let mimeType = "image/jpg"
        
        //Create http body
        var body = Data()
        let boundaryPrefix = " — \(boundary)\r\n"
        
        //Add the parameter to the body (Currently just leaf recognition is possible)
        body.append("--\(boundaryPrefix)\r\n")
        body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"organs\r\n\r\n")
        body.append("leaf\r\n")
        
        //Add the images to the body
        var filename = String()
        for (index,data) in imagesJPG.enumerated(){
            filename = "image\(index)"
            body.append(boundaryPrefix)
            body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image[]\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
            body.append("Content-Type: \(mimeType)\r\n\r\n")
            body.append(data)
            body.append("\r\n")
        }
        
        body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
        
        
        //Post the request
        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let response = response {
                print(response)
            }
                    
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                    print(json)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    func convertImagesToJPEG(images: [UIImage]) -> [Data] {
        var dataArray = [Data]()
        
        for i in images {
            if let data = i.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) {
                dataArray.append(data)
            }
        }
        
        return dataArray
    }
}

extension Data {
    mutating func append(_ string: String) {
        if let data = string.data(using: .utf8) {
            append(data)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The API key isn't working (placeholder for stack overflow), if you need one just leave a comment

Comment: https://my.plantnet.org/usage (this is the working link if you aren't logged in)

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Hi there, I'm one of the developer working on Pl@ntNet, let us know if this still needs help, if not, please either answer your question. 
Also, I'm redacting your API Key